# What's the earliest a champion can have a focus pool of 3?

Tags: optimization, character-levels, spellcasting, pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

In Pathfinder 2e, some classes have access to a *focus pool*. Each pool has a certain number of focus points, which can be used to cast spells.

I'm playing a champion and intending on making extensive use of focus spells. My focus pool has a maximum value of 3. What is the lowest level that I can have a focus pool of 3?

Comment: Notable - doesn't change the question or the answer, but is useful to know: unless you have other abilities which let you regain multiple focus points at once, you can only regain 1 focus point per combat (you can only regain if you've spent a focus point since you last regained)

Comment: Where does the "regain 1 focus point per combat" thing come from? Refocusing takes 10 minutes; I can't imagine doing that in combat!

Comment: It's not that you do it in combat, it's that the [refocus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=71) activity has a prerequisite that you have spent 1 focus point since you last regained focus points. So if you have 3 points, and you spend all 3 in one fight, you'd refocus to gain 1 back and then wouldn't be able to refocus until you spend that 1. With 3 points in your pool you have a bigger buffer, but you can only consistently use one per fight with 10 minutes of refocusing between fights.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## This is now possible at Level 4

The Advanced Player's Guide made this possible at level 4 through several methods - the Blessed One path works best for champions with the Tenets of Evil (to avoid redundant Lay on Hands), but now even Tenets of Good champions can get 3 focus points by level 4 without duplication through the Psychic archetype:

- Level 1: **Devotion Spells** grants you a Focus Point regardless of your Cause - we'll take any evil one to get Touch of Corruption.
- Level 2: Take the [Blessed One archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1910) - this gives us Lay on Hands and another Focus Point. Alternatively, take the [Psychic dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3736) - you'll need Int 14 or Cha 14 to do so.
- Level 4: Take either [Blessed Sacrifice](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1911) from the Blessed One archetype (unless you took the Psychic archetype), or [Sun Blade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1090) or [Light of Revelation](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1089) as Champion class feats.

Comment: +1 for finding a faster route. Would you consider removing the "questionable methods"? It's not that they are questionable, it's that they rely on GM fiat. If I could rely on that, I could have this licked at level 1.

Comment: @indigochild sure thing!! It's been removed!

Comment: Now Psychic dedication can also be used instead of Blessed One

Comment: @András good (and important) catch, added! This is very helpful for good aligned champions

Comment: @ESCE Warp Step is quite useful amped.

Answer (score 9):

As a champion, you can get a focus pool of 3 at level 6 by taking multiclass archetype feats. One possible path:

- Level 1: **Devotion Spells** champion class feature, getting one focus point.
- Level 2: **Monk Dedication** feat.
- Level 4: **Basic Kata** feat, granting the **Ki Rush** or **Ki Strike** feats, which grant a second focus point.
- Level 6: **Litany Against Wrath** feat, granting a third focus point.

The text of **Ki Rush** and **Ki Strike** says they grant a focus pool with one point, but the [Focus Points from Multiple Sources](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276) sidebar makes it clear that this will increase the size of an existing focus pool.

You can swap out the monk dedication for any other multiclass archetype to a class which has a level 1 or 2 feat which grants a focus point.

Comment: Why Monk? It is much easier to qualify for Sorcerer or Bard, and both can give you an FP on level 4

Comment: No particular reason, it was just the first one that came to mind when I answered the question.

Answer (score -2):

As a champion, you can get a focus pool of 3 at level 4.

- Level 1: Devotion Spells, gaining one Focus point from Lay on Hands.
- Level 1: Deity's Domain, gaining a second focus point.
- Level 2: Monk Dedication feat
- Level 4: Basic Kata feat, gaining Ki Rush or Ki Strike, which gives a
  third focus point.

Comment: You do _not_ get a second FP from Deity's Domain

Comment: I literally just asked that question and was told overwhelmingly that you do. https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/199282/does-the-order-in-which-you-take-focus-spells-change-the-size-of-your-focus-pool

Comment: The book says you raise your focus pool capacity by one any time you would gain a focus pool but already have one. It also says that you gain a focus pool any time you gain a focus spell. Deity's Domain gives you a focus spell, therefore it gives you a focus pool, therefore it raise your pool capacity by one if you already have a pool.

 "Let’s say you then took the champion multiclass archetype and the Healing Touch feat. Normally, this feat would give you a focus pool. Since you already have one, it instead increases your existing pool’s capacity by 1."

Comment: The book says you get a focus pool when you get a focus spell, _if you do not already have one_.  It is different getting Deity's Domain as a champion, and as something else with multiclass.