# Does the order in which you take Focus Spells change the size of your focus pool?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, focus-pool

For the purposes of this example, say I'm a Monk with the Summoner Multiclass Dedication, and no focus points to start. If I take the following feats, how many focus points will I have in my pool? One or two?

- Ki Rush "You gain the ki rush ki spell and a focus pool of 1 Focus Point."
- Eidolon's Wrath "Increase the number of Focus Points in your
  focus pool by 1"

If I take Ki Rush first, I gain a focus pool of 1, and then increase that pool to 2 after taking Eidolon's Wrath.

If I take Eidolon's Wrath first, I gain a focus pool of 1, and then do not increase my focus pool for taking Ki Rush, because I already have a focus pool.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 15):

## You have two Focus Points either way

This is addressed pretty explicitly in the rules on [Focus Points](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=276), except with the example of a Cleric with the Champion archetype:

> For instance, if you were a cleric with the Domain Initiate feat, you would have a pool with 1 Focus Point. Let’s say you then took the champion multiclass archetype and the Healing Touch feat. **Normally, this feat would give you a focus pool. Since you already have one, it instead increases your existing pool’s capacity by 1.**

Ki Rush gives you a focus pool, but you already have one, so it increases your current one by 1.

So **ordering doesn't matter** (in the very least in this situation; I can't think of one where is does, although obviously my knowledge is not exhaustive).

Comment: Thank you. What about the case of Eidolon's Wrath and the Druid Multiclass "Order Spell" feat? Order Spell says: "If you don’t already have one, you gain a focus pool of 1 Focus Point"  The order in which you take each feat would matter in that case, correct?

Comment: @Strill Even there, the "one" is referencing a "focus **pool**". You will only ever have one pool. So you'd still get a focus point. The verbiage on this was errata'd iirc, and I believe the druid was hit by some language-focused errata as well, so it's possible that the Order Spell archetype feat needs to be updated with more clear language, but even as written, I think my answer still holds.

Comment: How about in the case of the Champion's feat "Deity's Domain" which does not give you a focus pool at all?

Comment: @Strill the TL;DR is that Paizo didn't do the best job of unifying the language around Focus Points and Pools at the get go - basically, every time you get a focus spell (unless I'm missing some really niche feat), it'll come with a focus point for your pool up to your pool's max of 3.

Answer (score 1):

## **There are circumstances where order matters**

The example in the OP is the same either way, but the order in which you take the Deity's Domain feat does matter, because it does not explicitly give you a focus pool.

> You automatically gain a focus pool of 1 Focus Point the first time you gain an ability that gives you a focus spell.

This means that if Deity's Domain is your first focus spell, then you gain a focus pool from it.  However, if it is not your first focus spell, you do not gain any focus points from it.

> For instance, if you were a cleric with the Domain Initiate feat, you would have a pool with 1 Focus Point. Let’s say you then took the champion multiclass archetype and the Healing Touch feat. Normally, this feat would give you a focus pool. Since you already have one, it instead increases your existing pool’s capacity by 1.

Most focus spells explicitly grant you a focus pool, therefore the above rule can apply to them, raising your focus pool by 1.  Deity's Domain, however, does not explicitly grant you a pool, which means it only grants a pool if it's your first focus spell.

In conclusion, if you are a monk:

- If you take Ki Rush, then multiclass into Champion and take Deity's Domain, you will have one focus point.
- If you multiclass into Champion and take Deity's Domain, then take Ki Rush, you will have two focus points.

Comment: Ah, so mixing the two is how the math can break. It felt like there was something odd about it, but I only considered cases with two Deity's Domain-like abilities or two Ki Rush-like abilities.